# error in bower install angular multiple select module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower

i want to install bower angular-multiple-select but getting this error every time,any help

```
$ bower install --savev angular-multiple-select

 bower EACCES        EACCES, open      '/home/ali/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/angular-  multiple-select_730ad'

> Stack trace: Error: EACCES, open
> '/home/ali/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/angular-multiple-select_730ad'

> Console trace: Error
   >     at StandardRenderer.error           (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
  >     at Logger.<anonymous>            (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
  >     at Logger.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

> ```
> at Logger.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-   logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
> at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
> at _rejected     (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
> at   /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
> at Promise.when (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
> at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
> at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44       System info: 
>     Bower version: 1.7.9 
>     Node version: 0.10.37 
>     OS: Linux
> ```

```
    > 3.2.0-97-generic x64
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you format both your command and the console output properly? It's difficult to see what's going on

Comment: As you can see the formatting is still terrible. Also I see you've used the `--savev` flag, which is an error on part of the developer. It should be just `--save`.

Comment: same error again...n also can use savev

Comment: See my answer for a possible fix. But bear in mind that although `--savev` won't throw an error, it won't persist the module to your bower.json, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux? You might need to use the `sudo` command. I.e.

```
sudo bower install --save angular-multiple-select
```

Comment: bower ESUDO ,Cannot be run with sudo because bower is a user command there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.